# Guardar un listview al cerrar la aplicacion y recuperarlo al abrirla

Tags: android, lista, listview, app

Tengo un listview personalizado, donde cada elemento tiene 6 TextView y 3 botones, y un LinearLayout con un background que cambia de color.
Necesito saber cual seria la mejor manera de guardar todo el listView al momento de que se cierre la app y poder recuperarlo al momento de volver a abrirla. Tambien necesito saber si hay alguna forma de guardar todo el listView y no cada TextView de cada elemento por separado.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Prueba a poner el mismo codigo en el metodo sobreescrito onResume

Comment: Puedes implementar guardado en base de datos y al iniciar recuperar estos datos, me parece amplia tu pregunta, revisa [ask] te sugiero separar en partes y agregar lo que hayas investigado o tratado de realizar, saludos!